# Relational Query and Combo Box in Access 365 Form

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-forms

I'm trying to create a form to pull records that are identified by a last name and first name. The user will enter a last name for the query and then see a combo box with the first names that match the last name entered. When the user selects a first name from the combo box, the matching record will populate.

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtOdH.png)

I've tried setting up the form with the last name query to run on load, the last name query as the record source for the form with a SELECT query in the row source for the first name combo box, and the last name and first name in one combo box. Nothing has successfully loaded the combo box and the record.

[[Form View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1hZK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDoPK.png)

Comment: This is called "cascading combobox" and a common topic. Providing just form design is not useful. What code are you using to requery firstname combobox and to filter form? And what code did you try with the single combobox approach?